# Can the BindingNavigator check relations before deleting?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, data-binding

I have two DataGridView, one with products, and the other one with invoices.
The invoices contain data and the product, which is foreign referencing to products.

When creating the DataGridView, the BindingNavigator is automatically generated. Add, delete, edit and save in DB, all work fine.

The problem comes when it allows me to remove a product that appears on an invoice. When saving to the BD, a foreign key error jumps.

For now, I capture the deletion event, make a query to DB and search for the product to be deleted in the invoices table. If the product is in the invoice table, I cancel the operation and print a message.

There is any 'built-in' way of checking this without doing it manually? Or this is the way to go?

Comment: your FK did what its supposed to do. Why not put this into a `try...catch` so you only need to react when something went wrong, instead of checking yourself everytime again and again.

Comment: @GuidoG If the user deletes 8 products and the error happens, how can i recover the data that shouldn't be removed? Sorry for my english btw :S

Comment: if the error happens on the 8th product, do the prior 7 also need to be restored or may they stay deleted ? My guess is they may stay deleted and in that case there is no problem

Comment: To make it clear, when the FK error pops up, no actual deletion has happend for this product. So there is actually nothing to recover

Comment: It's removed from the DataGrid, which is not 'true' as the DB still has the product on it.

Comment: so, in your catch you could refresh your datagrid's datasource so it shows the row again

Comment: @GuidoG, true, I'll try that

Comment: Or you could not delete the row from the grid until you have done a succesfull delete in your DB. Its up to you what you prefer

Comment: @GuidoG In that case, the deletion would be manual instead of updating from the BindingSource, right?

Comment: yes, some do it like that and some dont. Its up to you what you prefer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Can the BindingNavigator check relations before deleting?**

Not automatically. You need to do it manually. To do so, you should set `DeleteItem` property of the `BindingNavigator` to `None` in designer and then handle click event of delete item. Then in the click event handler, using the `Current` property of the `BindingSource` you can get the current item and check some criteria and if it's fine to remove the item, remove it by calling `RemoveCurrent` method of the `BindingSource`. For example:

```
Private Sub BindingNavigatorDeleteItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
Handles BindingNavigatorDeleteItem.Click
    If ProductsBindingSource.Current IsNot Nothing
        Dim product = ctype(ProductBindingSource.Current, DataRowView)
        ' Check criteria, for example:
        If product.Row.Field(Of Integer)("Price") < 1000
            ProductsBindingSource.RemoveCurrent()
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("You cannot remove this product")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```